# Windows service in created and started in Delphi, bot not properly running

Tags: delphi, service

Hi i have created windows services in Delphi. I have installed and started the Services. Every thing working fine. Even i can check it in Task Manager.My service is Running.

But the code which i included inside the OnExecute method is not working.

My whole Code:

```
unit MyService;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,Jira;

type
  TJiraTestlink = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  JiraTestlink: TJiraTestlink;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  JiraTestlink.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TJiraTestlink.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TJiraTestlink.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
const
  SecBetweenRuns = 10;
var
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Count := 0;
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Inc(Count);
    if Count >= SecBetweenRuns then
    begin
      Count := 0;

      { place your service code here }
      { this is where the action happens }
      ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(Now));

    end;
    Sleep(1000);
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
  end;
end;
end.
```

I am not sure where i did mistake. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't count? or it doesn't show the message? For the latter, use OutputDebugString with DebugView or similar or write to a file or search for service desktop interaction vista...

Comment: If you are running it on XP or W2000, you have to set the interactive flag to enable ShowMessage from your service. On Vista and above you can't have an interactive service like David said in his answer.

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Vista, services are isolated and run in session 0, a non-interactive session. Interactive processes run in different sessions, starting from session 1 for the first logged on user.

This means that you cannot use your service to show UI. Calls to `ShowMessage` cannot work, by design, in a service.

You will need to find some other way to debug your service. For instance logging messages to a text file. Or `OutputDebugString` and a viewer like SysInternals DebugView which is capable of catching these debug strings from different sessions.

Comment: Although what you say is generally true, in the specific case that you simply want to display a popup message box from a service, you can use `MessageBox()` with the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag, or `WTSSendMessage()`. This is documented on MSDN: [Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502.aspx)

Comment: The documentation says MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION is not supported on Vista and later. Yes you can use WTSSendMessage but that's an appalling choice for debugging, which is what the askers message box is all about.

Comment: Actually, the documentation itself does not say that, but a user comment on the documentation does.  However, `WTSSendMessage()` has been around since Win2000, so if you need to support pre-Vista systems, you could dynamically load `WTSSendMessage()` and fall back to `MessageBox()` if unavailable. But either way, I wasn't suggesting to use message boxes for debugging a service, I was merely mentioning that it is an available option in general.

Comment: @Remy Actually the documentation does say that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502.aspx but I guess you refer to the MessageBox docs which presumably omit this important point. Ho hum.

Comment: I looked at that page before posting my previous comment. Nowhere does it specifically say that `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` is not supported on Vista and later. All it does is omits `MessageBox()` itself as a suggestion for those versions. That is not the same thing as being unsupported. You like to nitpick when other people are off on details. You need to pay attention to your own details, too.

Comment: @Remy Nit-picking is a rather pejorative term. I just think that details matter, as I'm sure do you. I certainly do try to pay attention to my own details. Do you disagree? And here my point is that one of the options you mentioned is no good on Vista+. I guess I read that doc differently from you. I read that doc as implying that MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION is not supported beyond ver 5.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59832/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-david-heffernan).